# RabbitMQ clustering on Digital Ocean

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq, cluster-computing

I have 2 droplets with Ubuntu 14.04, fresh clean rabbitmq server.
The same erlang cookie is made.
In the /etc/hosts of the server#2 I wrote the ip address of server#1, ping works, I can telnet to ports 4369 and 44001. 44001 is configured on both servers in the rabbitmq.config to fix the erlang port.

And followed the document by RabbitMQ, but I receive this:
rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@10....
or with
rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@server_name_#2

Clustering node rabbit@apn with 'rabbit@10.131.160.45' ...
Error: {cannot_discover_cluster,"The nodes provided are either offline or not running"}

How can I debug what is the issue? I seemed to made all changes required, but something is still missing.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: I edited the file
/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie
while the server was running and even after executing the restart init.d script, the server failed to stop and restart was also failed.
Had manually kill the processes and restart the servers again and make the cluster binding. Success.